# file not found while using powerautomate to get file content dynamically from a list

Tags: sharepoint, ms-word, power-automate

i am trying to get a file content using path to dynamically populate a word document with texts and image from a SharePoint list but Iam getting an error message file not found however if i select the image from the list directly the flow run successfully the file will be created.

[image]

solution to the problem